# YouTube Python Game

Tags: python, youtube

So I have a Python program that uses splinter and will go to YouTube and search random words from the dictionary the problem is that it only types one word and then searches and I want it to type three random words that are all different then search those words. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import splinter, random
from splinter import *

browser = Browser()
filePath = "words.txt"

wordList = []

file = open(filePath, 'rU')

for line in file:
    wordList.append(line)

myWord = random.choice(wordList)

browser.visit('https://www.youtube.com')
browser.fill('search_query', myWord)
```

Comment: What actually is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a specific number of unique, random values from a list, you can use `sample`:

```
myWords = random.sample(wordList, 3) # returns a list
myWords_query = ' '.join(myWords) # so turn it into a space separated string
...
browser.fill('search_query', myWords_query)
```

Comment: Okay I think I get it the sample part is what you want to take from(such as a file) and the number is how many or the line number you want to take?

Comment: When in doubt, always [check the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample), the standard library docs are especially good. But yes, sample takes two arguments: the first is a sequence of items to choose from, the second is the number of items to choose. The items are guaranteed to be unique as well.